# Downloading content in the background

Tags: c#

I wrote this `downloadContent()` function.

Is there some other way to download the content faster?

```
private string downloadContent() 
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(testingUrl);
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Method = "GET";
        response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return content;
    }
    catch
    {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Here the two functions I'm using to extract the text from in between tags after downloading:

```
private void GetProfileNames(string text)
{
    names = new List<string>();
    string startTag = "<span class=\"message-profile-name\" ><a  href='/profile/";
    string endTag = "'>";
    int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
    int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
    index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        index = text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
        int start = index + startTagWidth;
        index = text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // found the endTag 
        profileName = text.Substring(start, index - start);
        names.Add(profileName);
    }
}
```

And this is the `DoWork()` event which is not good the way I did it, but I just don't know how to make it better:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    string templastItem;
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker; 
    List<string> tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
    string tempDownload = downloadContent();
    if (tempDownload == error)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "===> " + "Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect" + Environment.NewLine)));
            Logger.Write("Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GetProfileNames(tempDownload);
        GetTextFromProfile(tempDownload);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            tempNamesAndTexts.Add(names[i] + " " + texts[i]);

        }
        templastItem = tempNamesAndTexts.Last();
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tempNamesAndTexts.ForEach(Item => textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "===> " + Item + Environment.NewLine))));
            string[] array = File.ReadAllLines(full_path_log_file_name);
            if (array.Length == 2)
            {
                foreach (string item in tempNamesAndTexts)
                {
                    Logger.Write(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!array.Contains(templastItem))
                {
                    Logger.Write(templastItem);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        testingDownload = downloadContent();
        if (testingDownload == error)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "===> " + "Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect" + Environment.NewLine)));
                Logger.Write("Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        else
        {
            Logger.exist();
            namesAndTexts = new List<string>();
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {



                string content = downloadContent();
                if (content == error)
                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "===> " + "Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect" + Environment.NewLine)));
                        Logger.Write("Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {

                    GetProfileNames(content);
                    GetTextFromProfile(content);
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                    {
                        namesAndTexts.Add(names[i] + " " + texts[i]);

                    }
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        result = tempNamesAndTexts.SequenceEqual(namesAndTexts);
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var t = namesAndTexts.Last();


                            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                            {

                                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "===> " + t + Environment.NewLine)), null);
                                Logger.Write(t);
                                if (result == false)
                                {
                                    tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                                    {

                                        tempNamesAndTexts.Add(names[i] + " " + texts[i]);
                                    }
                                }



                            }
                        }


                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private void GetTextFromProfile(string text)
{
    texts = new List<string>();
    string str = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
    string startTag = str;
    string endTag = "</span>";
    int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
    int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
    index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        index = text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
        int start = index + startTagWidth;
        index = text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        // found the endTag 
        profileNameText = text.Substring(start, index - start);
        Conditions();


    }
}
```

[This](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3B8A7D9F66FF985B!171&authkey=!AFO6EmoF38MtkKQ) is the link to view/download the project, which is not big.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about faster, but please make sure you wrap your disposable resources (classes which implement `IDisposable`) in `using` statements to properly and deterministically manage resources:

```
    private string downloadContent() 
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(testingUrl);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Method = "GET";
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, I like the use of white space and the layout.

On top of what Jesse said here's my $0.02

I think you're using too many class variables in this code.  You also have way too many nested ifs.  I have noted below where you should be removing the nesting and why it is not needed.

Start in the *GetProfileNames* method.  The while the loop works, but it is very messy, and the while(true) statement really confuses the code. I would try something like this, it is cleaner, and probably more efficient

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetProfileNames(string text)
{
    const string startTag = "<span class=\"message-profile-name\" ><a  href='/profile/";
    const string endTag = "'>";

    var names = text.Split(new[] {startTag, endTag}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return names;
}
```

Modify your *Conditions* method to be something a little more descriptive.  You should change the signature too so you can pass in the string you're processing.  This will clarify what call is supposed to be doing.

```
private void ProcessProfileNameTexts(string profileNameText)
{
    ...
}
```

You can then apply the same logic as you did in *GetProfileNames* to *GetTextFromProfile*

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetTextFromProfile(string text)
{

    const string startTag = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
    const string endTag = "</span>";

    var texts = text.Split(new[] { startTag, endTag }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    texts.ForEach(ProcessProfileNameTexts);

    return texts;
}
```

Your DoWork method is a mess.  I would start by adding a return to the if of the error check and removing the else.  I would also stop using the '+' to concatenate strings, this is a very inefficient way of doing it.  My suggestion would be to use string.Format()

First off, add a few helper methods

```
private static void Invoke(string message)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(string.Format(@"{0} ===> {1}", DateTime.Now, message))));
}

private static void Log(string message)
{
    Logger.Write(message);
}

private static void InvokeAndLogIfRequired(string message, string loggerMessage)
{
    if (!InvokeRequired)
    {
        return;
    }

    Invoke(message);
    Log(loggerMessage);
}
```

Then change your error check to

```
if (tempDownload == error)
{

    InvokeAndLogIfRequired(
        string.Format(@"Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect{0}", Environment.NewLine), 
        "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");


    return;
}
```

Your method lists can then be assigned:

```
names = GetProfileNames(tempDownload);
texts = GetTextFromProfile(tempDownload);

var tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    tempNamesAndTexts .Add(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", names[i], texts[i]));
}
```

The variable templastItem should be declared as it is assigned

```
var templastItem = tempNamesAndTexts.Last();
```

This next section is not as clean as I'd like, but it is a little cleaner that the original code.

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    tempNamesAndTexts.ForEach(Invoke);

    var array = File.ReadAllLines(full_path_log_file_name);
    if (array.Length == 2)
    {
        tempNamesAndTexts .ForEach(Log);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!array.Contains(templastItem))
        {
            Log(templastItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not going to take out the next while loop because I don't think I have that much brain power right now, but lets clean it up:

Make the error reporting a little cleaner but using helper methods and adding a *continue* instead of the else statement

```
testingDownload = downloadContent();
if (testingDownload == error)
{
    InvokeAndLogIfRequired("Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect", "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    continue;
}
```

Remove the else from the cancel pending code too.  The *break* takes care of the else.

```
Logger.exist();
var namesAndTexts = new List<string>();
if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    break;
}
```

Clean up the next error checking:

```
string content = downloadContent();
if (content == error)
{
    InvokeAndLogIfRequired(
        string.Format(@"Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect{0}", Environment.NewLine),
        "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    continue;
}
```

Now comes to the last Invoke, going to start after the if statement:

The if here is useless.  Check for false and continue through the false path.

```
result = tempNamesAndTexts.SequenceEqual(namesAndTexts);
if (result == true)
{
}
```

Like this:

```
result = tempNamesAndTexts.SequenceEqual(namesAndTexts);
if (result == false)
{
    ...
}
```

This next section is very confusing, within the

```
if (InvokeRequired)
```

you have

```
if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
```

I'm assuming this is the same thing.  If it is, the second one will **ALWAYS** be true.

you also have a

```
if (result == false)
```

inside a

```
if (result == false)
```

again, the second one will **ALWAYS** be false, remove it.

These suggestions just scratch the surface, there is much more I could do to this, but this is a good start.

Here is the entire DoWork method as I've refactored it, I haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    string tempDownload = downloadContent();
    if (tempDownload == error)
    {
        InvokeIfRequires(
            string.Format(@"Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect{0}",
                            Environment.NewLine),
            "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");


        return;
    }

    names = GetProfileNames(tempDownload);
    texts = GetTextFromProfile(tempDownload);
    var tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
        tempNamesAndTexts.Add(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", names[i], texts[i]));
    }

    var templastItem = tempNamesAndTexts.Last();

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        tempNamesAndTexts.ForEach(Invoke);

        var array = File.ReadAllLines(full_path_log_file_name);
        if (array.Length == 2)
        {
            tempNamesAndTexts.ForEach(Log);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!array.Contains(templastItem))
            {
                Log(templastItem);
            }
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        testingDownload = downloadContent();
        if (testingDownload == error)
        {
            InvokeAndLogIfRequired("Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect",
                                    "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Maybe put a count in here so you don't end up in an infinite loop of the web server is down
            continue;
        }

        Logger.exist();

        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        string content = downloadContent();
        if (content == error)
        {
            InvokeAndLogIfRequired(
                string.Format(@"Error The Web Site Is Not Responding Wait, Trying To Reconnect{0}",
                                Environment.NewLine),
                "Error The Web Site Was Not Responding");

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Maybe put a count in here so you don't end up in an infinite loop of the web server is down


            continue;
        }


        var namesAndTexts = new List<string>();
        names = GetProfileNames(content);
        texts = GetTextFromProfile(content);
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            namesAndTexts.Add(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", names[i], texts[i]));

        }

        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            result = tempNamesAndTexts.SequenceEqual(namesAndTexts);
            if (result == false)
            {
                var lastText = namesAndTexts.Last();
                Invoke(lastText);
                Log(lastText);
            }
        }

        tempNamesAndTexts = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {

            tempNamesAndTexts.Add(string.Format(@"{0} {1}", names[i], texts[i]));
        }

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice review Jeff, just two points I'd like to make: check out the first edit of the question, and you'll see I fixed the whitespace ;) and using `ProcessProfileNameTexts` like you suggest can't work because you're only replacing the parameter, right? parameters in C# are passed by value, so you're *not modifying the original reference*.

Comment: forget the second one, I hadn't read the whole thing. However, the static helper methods need to be instance methods because they access `Invoke`, which is an instance method of `Form`.

Comment: Thanks.  It's hard to track some of those things without having the whole file.  I would of picked that stuff up if I had it in front of me...and moving those around could be phase 2, as well as cleaning the multiple calls too downloadContent().  I think you need to clean the rest of it before tackling that.

Comment: Jeff Vanzella this is the link to my complete project with all files. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3B8A7D9F66FF985B!171&authkey=!AFO6EmoF38MtkKQ

Comment: I saw it, just didn't really have time to study it today.  I'll look at it a little closer tomorrow :)